# Standard Users able to install games without Administrator

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, steam

I've setup some permissions through Group Policy (Windows Professional). One of these are restricting access to all the drives. These computers are for gaming, thus they can use steam, Battle.net and other game platforms. The problem is we don't want the drives filling up with unwanted data. Group Policy can restrict them from accessing the drives through File Explorer, and can restrict them from installing files from a browser. The problem is I have yet not found a way to restrict users from installing their own games on the system through the game platform (i.e. Steam). Help?

Comment: how are your group's game installations/Updates managed?

Comment: This will be difficult.  Most Steam games are not installed in the traditional sense. Same goes for all the other game platforms, if you are not installing through an MSI, you won't be able to prevent a user with only User permission from downloading games they are licensed to have (I presume you allow the use of their own account). One solution might be, preventing them from having to write access, but sounds more trouble then it is worst. Use something that rolls the HDD back to a specific version each time the machine is restarted. Use policy that if broken prevents the use of said machine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like these are publicly used computers, like a internet/game cafe.  There are many software products that will roll Windows back to a set image.  In a public environment, this is actually good, as you never know what can get messed up accidentally or on purpose.  If an automatic game update breaks the game, you can just roll back.  If the user somehow gets malware on your system, just roll back.  You can install popular items like Steam and other games to reduce rollback time.

Software products like [Reboot Restore Rx](http://horizondatasys.com/reboot-restore-rx-freeware/) are designed to do this.  There are others, you can just google them.